# ListView inside PopupDialog is null

Tags: java, android

In my application I am trying to use a `ListView` inside a `PopupDialog`. This is done inside of an `AsyncTask`. I think the issue lies somewhere between the `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute`.....everything is returning correctly, but the `list = null` after I use `findViewById()`. I can't figure out why......Note, the AsyncTask and Adapter are both inner classes.

```
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateNewReport.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(CreateNewReport.this);
        popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_expenses, null);

        alert.setTitle("Add Expenses").setView(popupView);

        alert.setNeutralButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            }
        });

        alert.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<Expense> expenses){
        availableExpenses = expenses;

        // create list adapter for available expenses
        ArrayAdapter<Expense> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Expense>(CreateNewReport.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, expenses);

        // get a reference to the list
        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAvailableExpenses);

        // set the list adapter
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // find widgets
        final ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading_expenses);
        final LinearLayout listLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.available_expenses);
        final LinearLayout progressContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.available_expenses_loading);

        // change visibility as needed
        progressContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        listLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

**XML for the popup box**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ProgressBar
         android:id="@+id/loading_expenses"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewAvailableExpenses"
            style="@style/Container"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `findViewById()` call is looking for your list inside the Activity (it's a method of the Activity instance), but your list is inside the dialog. Instead, you need to save a reference to the dialog and then do `theDialog.findViewById(R.id.ListNote)`:

```
//PreExecute
theDialog = alert.create(); //theDialog is an instance variable of the asynctask
theDialog.show();


//PostExecute
final ListView list = (ListView) theDialog.findViewById(R.id.ListNote);
```